# AirDrop a custom file type from one IOS device to another / excludedActivityTypes

Tags: swift, xcode, mime-types, airdrop

Currently I can send custom type Data from one device to another via email but I'm now trying to use AirDrop with my incomplete code below . I think the problem is I need to add my custom file type in the excludedActivityTypes but not sure how ??

I believe I need to add my document type and exported type identifier but not sure how ? (I've added screen shots below of my declared custom file)

```
enter code here   let dataToShare: NSMutableArray = self.quizDataBase

       let controller = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [dataToShare], applicationActivities: nil)
    controller.excludedActivityTypes = nil

    self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

[image]